# Is github1s.com safe or not ? Can we use it for private repo?

Tags: angular, github, visual-studio-code

Recently, I found `https://github1s.com` to see github repository as open in *vscode* editor in browser itself & I think it's a great tool to analyse the code.

e.g. https://github1s.com/angular/angular

Anyone knows, Is it safe to use or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a public project: [`conwnet/github1s`](https://github.com/conwnet/github1s), which means it can be audited in order to check its safety.

You can see making its own FS (FileSystem) in [`extensions/github1s/src/github1sfs.ts`](https://github.com/conwnet/github1s/blob/26343837f839d997afc67c065fd79c2ec6e05a06/extensions/github1s/src/github1sfs.ts#L64-L76).

And you can check how it manages the OAuth token in [`extensions/github1s/src/settings-view.ts`](https://github.com/conwnet/github1s/blob/26343837f839d997afc67c065fd79c2ec6e05a06/extensions/github1s/src/settings-view.ts#L38-L56), used when fetching the file in [`extensions/github1s/src/util/fetch.ts`](https://github.com/conwnet/github1s/blob/26343837f839d997afc67c065fd79c2ec6e05a06/extensions/github1s/src/util/fetch.ts#L54-L78)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, seems pretty safe to me.

If it asks you to log into GitHub with like the GitHub "auth this app to do this" screen then your safe.

If it DIRECTLY asks your for your GitHub USERNAME and PASSWORD then exit the website and... don't visit it again.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use https://github.surf/angular/angular

> github.surf

this is maintained by more professional contributors